# Save Audio Features extracted using Librosa in a multichannel Numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, keras, conv-neural-network, librosa

I am trying to extract features from audio files using Librosa, to feed to a CNN as Numpy arrays.

Currently i save a single feature at a time to feed into the CNN. I save two dimensional (single-channel) log-scaled mel-spectrogram features in Python using `Librosa`:

```
def build_features():
    y, sr = librosa.load("audio.wav")
    mel = librosa.feature.melspectrogram(
        n_fft=4096,
        n_mels=128, #Mel-bins
        hop_length=2048,
    )
    logamplitude = librosa.amplitude_to_db
    logspec = logamplitude(mel, ref=1.0)[np.newaxis, :, :, np.newaxis]
```

This gives the shape `(1,128,323,1)`.

I would like to add another feature, let's say a `tempogram`. I can do this, using the same code, but replacing **melspectrogram** to **tempogram'**, and setting the window length to `128`.

This gives me a `tempogram` shape of `(1,128,323,1)`.

Now i would like to "stack" these 2 feature layers, into a multi-channel numpy object, that i can feed into a CNN in Keras.

How should i code this?

**EDIT:**

Think I figured it out, using np.vstack()

Comment: How did this work for you? I'm thinking about doing something similar :)

Comment: Hi Zach, it did not get much better by adding more features, only a lot slower! :)

Comment: Good to know! Thanks for saving me some time haha -- anything that worked very well?

Comment: Get as much test data as you can get your hands on! I only had around 3k available data points, which is not a lot when training from scratch.

Comment: Thanks! I've been using Spotify's API which is pretty generous in the amount of requests you can make so I may actually run into the opposite problem haha (too much data). Appreciate the tips!